# URL for a parameter? jQuery, Ajax, JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

Create an html page with a table and a button. When the button is clicked show results for the first 10 planets from the Star Wars api. The information in the table are:

Planet Name
Population
Climate
Gravity
**There should be a function that makes the call to the api for the planets ( should have URL for a parameter )** There should be a function that prints planets in to the table **API URL: ** https://swapi.co/api/planets/?page=1

This is my answer but i don't know how to pass the url as parametar... Help?!

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  let btn = $(".btn")
  btn.on("click", function bla () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://swapi.co/api/planets/?page=1",
        success: function (response) {
            let planetsObj = response;
            console.log(planetsObj)
            for (let i = 0; i < planetsObj.results.length; i++) {
                let firstTen = `<tr>  <td> ${planetsObj.results[i].name}</td> <td>${planetsObj.results[i].population} </td>  <td>${planetsObj.results[i].climate}</td> <td>${planetsObj.results[i].gravity}</td></tr>`
                $(".table").append(firstTen)
            }
        }
    })
  })

})
```

Answer (score 1):

You could define a function that accepts a parameter and call it from the buttons on click listener callback function.

Here is an example:

```
$(".btn").on("click", function() {
  getPlanets("https://swapi.co/api/planets/?page=1")
});

function getPlanets(URL) {
  $.ajax({
    url: URL,
    success: function (response) {
        ...  
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't fully understand your question, but I hope it will help you. I give you an example:

Note: Since ES6, you can use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 let btn = $(".btn");
 let btn_search = $("#btn_search");
 let table = $(".table");

 btn.on("click", function (e) {
  const page = $(this).attr('data-page');
  const searchText = "";
  callToApi(page, searchText);
 });

 btn_search.on("click", function (e) {
  const searchText = $("#search").val();
  const page = 1; // default value
  table.empty(); // clean table
  callToApi(page, searchText);
 });

 function callToApi(page, searchText) {
  $.ajax({
   // Template literals
   url: `https://swapi.co/api/planets/?page=${page}&search=${searchText}`,
   success: function (response) {
    let planetsObj = response;
    for (let i = 0; i < planetsObj.results.length; i++) {
     let firstTen = `<tr>  <td> ${planetsObj.results[i].name}</td> <td>${planetsObj.results[i].population} </td>  <td>${planetsObj.results[i].climate}</td> <td>${planetsObj.results[i].gravity}</td></tr>`
     table.append(firstTen)
    }
   }

  })
 }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Search:</label>
<input id="search" />
<button id="btn_search">
Search
</button>

<table class="table">

</table>
<br/>
<br/>

<button class="btn" data-page="1">
Load Page 1
</button>
<button class="btn" data-page="2">
Load Page 2
</button>
```